# csrf token validation fail in post request while calling sap odata service

Tags: node.js, odata, csrf

```
 var Array = require('node-array');
    var request = require("request");
username = "user24",
password = "",
      auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
var options = { method: 'GET',
url:  "http://207.188.73.88:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTEE_SUGGEST_SRV/ZteeSuggestSet?$filter=Number eq 5 and Date eq datetime'2014-03-11T00%3A00%3A00'&$format=json",
headers: 
{
```

i am fetching xcsrf token here

```
    'x-csrf-token': 'fetch',
   'content-type': 'application/json',
    authorization: auth } };

      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) throw new Error(error);
     // console.log(response.headers['x-csrf-token']);
     var token="'";
       token+=response.headers['x-csrf-token'];
        token+="'";
         //console.log(token);
      var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://207.188.73.88:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTEE_TIME_SRV/ZTEERESERVESet',
```

and setting the csrf token here but it give me error that scrf token required or invalid

```
  headers: 
   {
 authorization: auth,
 'x-csrf-token': token,
 'content-type': 'application/json' },
 body: 
 { Time: 'time\'PT11H00M00S\'',
 Date: 'datetime\'2014-03-11T00%3A00%3A00\'',
 Location: 'AAJ',
 Number: 3 },
 json: true };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
```

//               console.log(body);
here it shows that token rrequired but i am already setting that in header

```
                  console.log(response.headers['x-csrf-token']);
            });




         });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar situation while working with SAP WEBIDE.

I had disabled the request for token and i was able to establish the connection with Odata services. I did something like this code snippet in my component.js file.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(this.getMetadata().getConfig().serviceUrl);
oModel.disableHeadRequestForToken = true;
```

**serviceURL** contained the URL to Odata Service. 
You can try to disable the CSRF token request and check.